# How to remove words of a sentence by using a dictionary as reference

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, stop-words, pos-tagger

I have a dictionary created and saved as a text file. I open it as

```
with open(pathDoc+'/WordsDictionary.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf8") as inf:
wordsDictionary = eval(inf.read())
```

saved format is this: `{'word1':'tag1', 'word2':'tag2'}`

when a sentence is given, i want to remove words that belong to a certain tag set. (simply what is done in `stop words removal in nltk`, but this is for a language that is not supported by nltk toolkit). example is given below.

```
 wordsDictionary = {'word1':'tag1', 'word2':'tag2', 'word3':'tag3'}
    Sentence = "word1 word2 word3 word2 word1"
# I want to remove words that belong to 'tag2' type
FinalSentence = "word1 word3 word1"
```

How can i generate `FinalSentence`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@haifzhan's solution will get you there for use cases of one word per tag.  If you however need more than one word per tag, here's another solution:

```
sentence = "word1 word2 word3 word2 word1 word4 word5 word1"
tags = {'tag1': ['word1'], 'tag2': ['word4', 'word2'], 'tag3': ['word3']} # Set a dictionary of lists based on tags

final_sentence = ' '.join([word for word in sentence.split() if word not in tags.get('tag2')])

# Output:
final_sentence
'word1 word3 word1 word5 word1'
```

If your words are not delimited by space though you'll need to approach this a different way, maybe like this:

```
for word in tags.get('tag2'):
    sentence = sentence.replace(word,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the key and value pairs, so the words dictionary would be tags dictioanry. Then use `tag2` as key to get value `word2`

```
def reverse(words):
    return {v: k for k, v in words.items()}


tags = reverse(wordsDictionary)  #  {'tag1': 'word1', 'tag2': 'word2', 'tag3': 'word3'}
```

Replace value `word2` to empty string, tags.get('tag2') gives you the value `word2`

```
Sentence.replace(tags.get('tag2'), '')
```

Comment: That would only work if there's a limit of one word per tag.